# Assign a byte pointer to a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, reference, variable-assignment, dereference

This one is annoying me, but I want to avoid the obvious solution of just using memcpy.

```
struct Person
{
    //Some variables
};

void doSomething(char* pointerToSomeone)
{
    struct Person bob;

    //Assign pointerToSomeone to bob, somehow...
}
```

In the above, pointerToSomeone is a pointer to a Person struct.
How do I assign that to bob? Surely it's possible?

I've tried numerous what I thought were sensible casts, deferences, etc without success (compiler errors).

Comment: If this should change pointerToSomeone outsied doSth, you should use ** instead of *.

Comment: First off, if pointerToSomeone really points to a Person, why is it declared "char *"? It should be a pointer to the structure or else void *. Secondly, what do you actually mean by "assigning it to bob"? Do you mean making it point to the bob structure? That's just "pointerToSomeone = &bob", which will be valid for the scope of the function (but not outside it). Do you actually mean that you want to copy data from one structure to another? That needs memmove(). So what is it you're actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. However, if you are **sure** that `pointerToSomeone` really is a pointer to a `Person` then you could make `bob` a pointer and use type-casting:

```
struct Person *bob = (struct Person *) pointerToSomeone;
```

Comment: Bingo. I knew using a local variable in the way I was doing was nonsensical somehow!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign a pointer to `char` to a `struct`, but you can copy the content pointed to by the `char*` into a `struct`, like this:

```
memcpy(&bob, pointerToSomeone, sizeof(struct Person));
```

In cases when the `pointerToSomeone` is untyped, it is more common to use `void*` instead of `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do this (assuming, that it's a valid cast):

```
struct Person bob = *((struct Person*) pointerToSomeone);
```

Beware that you're copying the stack of the pointer and not referencing to it as you would do with this:

```
struct Person* bob = (struct Person*) pointerToSomeone;
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply copy the struct pointed to by `pointerToSomeone` to `bob` with `memcpy`, just make sure pointerToSomeone really was pointer to a struct Person

```
void doSomething(char* pointerToSomeone)
{
    struct Person bob;

    memcpy( &bob , pointerToSomeone , sizeof( struct Person ) ) ;

}
```